# "much of the sights" or "many of the sights"?

Tags: determiners, dialect, countable-nouns

In this conversation, two people are talking about travelling when one of them says the following sentence:

> I went to Paris once, but I didn't see MUCH OF the sights.

I think "sights" in this sense is a  plural countable noun which  means "interesting places"; so shouldn't it be "many of" not "much of"?

Comment: There's a song - *So Much Things to Say*

Comment: Thanks Maulik. But why do you think Bob Marley has used "so much" in his song?

Comment: I don't know why Bob Marley wrote his lyrics the way he did, but *so much things to say* is not grammatical.

Comment: Simple - it's a song. Lyricists are not grammarians! ;)

Comment: Maybe you're right Maulik but we're not talking about subtle differences and I'm pretty sure that even Bob Marley knew about it quite well.

Comment: @M.N. Much of the English that Bob Marley sang in many of his songs (and, I presume, spoke) is not necessarily "standard English".  Most English speaker wouldn't say "Pirates sold I to the merchant ships," etc.  (That's touched upon in [a Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rastafari_movement#Language), by the way.)

Comment: @ Joshua Taylor: There are some very interesting points in the article you mentioned especially in the "Culture-Language" part where the reason for not using Standard English has been briefly explained. Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

You're right, *I didn't see many of the sights* is correct and means *I saw only a few or some of the number of interesting places*.

But, *I didn't see much of the sights* is also correct. The idiom *see much of* means *see frequently (especially in the recent past) or for long periods of time*, and is typically used in the negated form. For example, *I haven't seen much of my neighbors* means *I haven't seen my neighbors lately*. This is valid even with a countable plural noun such as *neighbors*.

*I didn't see much of the sights* means that I spent very little time sightseeing. This means that I took in very little of what they had to offer, and likely (but not necessarily) saw numerically few of them if there were a large number.

Comment: One small point: "I didn't see much of the sights" doesn't really imply that you saw numerically few of them. For example, you could have made very superficial visits to many places.

Comment: Indeed, good point.

Answer (score 1):

I guess in this context both can go.

If you consider sights like a unique idea of a landscape you may use “much of”, but if you consider sights like places as you described then you may use “many of”.

Answer (score 1):

This represents only my personal look into this:

much of - not a big part comparing to overall known or maybe assumable count, for example 2-3 places of 20. But there is also a drop of uncertainty in this sentence, because there may be total of 3 of places that can be visited.

This also can mean that visited places didn't reflected expectations, assuming a man visited 10 of 15 known places, but they weren't as exciting as other 5 left

many of - this mainly reflects an actual progress of travelling, because "many" will refer to low count of visited places.

Comment: I'd probably use "few of" to describe, say, 2-3 of 20.